# C++ Win32 data processing thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, client

I wrote a Win32 async client application and I would like to create a thread to proceed with incoming data separately. I have an issue with the following code. The thread is launched, gets some data but doesn't run properly (data is not complete). I do not see where the problem comes from. Could you please help me ?

```
void incData(void *arg) // This is the thread
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hIncDataMutex, INFINITE);

    char *sRead = _strdup(sReadBuffer.c_str());
    appendTextToEdit(hDebug, sRead); // Some data is displayed, but incompletely
    string var;
    char *pVar = nullptr;                   
    char *next_token = nullptr;

    istringstream iss(sReadBuffer); // sReadBuffer is the global variable I use to pass argument to my thread   

    while (getline(iss, var)) // Default delimiter '\n'
    {       
        pVar = _strdup(var.c_str()); // Cast string to char *
        appendTextToEdit(hDebug, pVar);
        appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "\n");

        if(strstr(pVar, "id=") != NULL)
        {   
            char *label = strtok_s(pVar, "=", &next_token);                     
            char *pId = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token);                          
            strcpy_s(id, pId);
        }

        if( strstr(pVar, "version") != NULL)
        {
            char *label = strtok_s(pVar, "=", &next_token);                     
            char *pVersion = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token);                     
            strcpy_s(version, pVersion);                        
        }       

        if( strstr(pVar, "Qh57=") != NULL)
        {
            char *label = strtok_s(pVar, "=", &next_token);     
            char *pFoFd = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token);                            
            strcpy_s(foFd, pFoFd);          
        }
    }
    ReleaseMutex(hIncDataMutex);
}

//.....

case FD_CONNECT: // I launch the thread here (I want it to run forever in the background)
{
    connectStatus = TRUE;
    statusText=TEXT("Connected");               

    hIncDataMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, false, NULL); // Create incoming data process thread mutex
    HANDLE hThread2 = (HANDLE)_beginthread(incData, 0, 0); // Launch incoming data process thread
}

//....

case FD_READ:
{   
    int bytes_recv = recv(Socket, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), 0);               

    sReadBuffer = readBuffer; // Copy the buffer to global scope string (used to feed thread)               

    ReleaseMutex(hIncDataMutex);
}
break;
```

**EDIT**

Here is my code with new debug lines, and the output from the debug window :

```
void incData(void *arg)
{
WaitForSingleObject(hIncDataMutex, INFINITE);
appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "Inside thread...\n");


string var;
char *pVar = nullptr;                   
char *next_token = nullptr;

istringstream iss(sReadBuffer); // Put into a stream            

while (getline(iss, var)) // Default delimiter '\n'
{       
    pVar = _strdup(var.c_str()); // Cast string to char *       

    if(strstr(pVar, "id=") != NULL)
    {   
        char *label = strtok_s(pVar, "=", &next_token);                     
        char *pId = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token);                          
        strcpy_s(id, pId);
    }

    if( strstr(pVar, "version") != NULL)
    {
        char *label = strtok_s(pVar, "=", &next_token);                     
        char *pVersion = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token);                     
        strcpy_s(version, pVersion);                        
    }       

    if( strstr(pVar, "Qh57=") != NULL)
    {
        char *label = strtok_s(pVar, "=", &next_token);     
        char *pFoFd = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token);                            
        strcpy_s(foFd, pFoFd);
        appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "Qh57=");
        appendTextToEdit(hDebug, foFd);
        appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "\n"); 
    }
}

ReleaseMutex(hIncDataMutex);
appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "Mutex released by thread\n");
}

//....

case FD_READ:
            {   
                appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "FD_READ event\n");            


                int bytes_recv = recv(Socket, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), 0);                   
                appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "Bytes reveived\n");
                sReadBuffer = readBuffer; // Copy the buffer to string
                ReleaseMutex(hIncDataMutex);
                appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "End of FD_READ\n");
            }
            break;
```

From the debug window :

```
FD_CONNECT, begining thread
FD_READ event
Bytes reveived
End of FD_READ
FD_READ event
Bytes reveived
End of FD_READ
Inside thread... // Thread is only called here !
FD_READ event
Bytes reveived
End of FD_READ
Mutex released by thread // Thread ends here
FD_READ event
Bytes reveived
End of FD_READ
```

etc...
Any idea ?

Comment: Is character 0x00 appearing somewhere in `readBuffer`? In that case both `string::operator=` in `sReadBuffer = readBuffer;` and `_strdup` in `char *sRead = _strdup(sReadBuffer.c_str());` will copy only the beginning of the buffer till character 0x00.

Comment: NO, no no!  You are copying buffers all over the place, including into/outof globals.  The thread holds a mutex for its entire processing run.  Threads are continually being created/terminated/destroyed.  No wonder things are going badly:(

Comment: Declare a buffer class, maybe with a vector to hold the data.  Create an instance, (new), load data, use a producer-consumer queue to signal the instance to the thread.  Start the thread once only and have it loop around the P-C queue pop, waiting for bufffer instances and processing them as they arrive.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the way you wait for the data on the mutex:  setting it on one side and never trying to set it on the other side clearly shows something is missing.

Here's what probably happens:

```
main thread                         processing thread
--------------------------------------------------
data A is received on FD_READ        waiting on mutex 
ReleaseMutex() --->                  start processing the data A
other data B is received                .. 
ReleaseMutex()                          .. end processing data A
still other C data overwrites B      ReleaseMutex()     
ReleaseMutex()                       waiting on mutex
                                     processing data C which has overwriten B
                                     ( ==> B is lost)
```

Avoid receiving data unless you can buffer it in a way that doesn't overwrite data that is not yet processed.  This usually requires setting the mutext when updating (filling) the shared data (i.e.before trying to copy the buffer). [This tutorial](http://www.mario-konrad.ch/wiki/doku.php?id=programming:multithreading:tutorial-06) could be or interest to you at least from the design principle.

**Important edit:**

Nothing to dowith multithreading, but don't forget that [`recv()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) doesn't guarantee a null terminated string.  So before copying it to a string, check for errors and put a trailing '\0'.  So as a first step you could try:

```
case FD_READ:
{   
    int bytes_recv = recv(Socket, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer),
0); 
    if (bytes_recv!=SOCKET_ERROR) {
        readBuffer[bytes_recv] = '\0'; //... trailing null 
        WaitForSingleObject(hIncDataMutex, INFINITE);
        sReadBuffer = readBuffer; // Copy the buffer to global scope string (used to feed thread)               

        ReleaseMutex(hIncDataMutex);

    }
    else cout << "Socket error"; 
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately, I have no idea of how to implement your advises in my code. I think I have to learn again about threads :-(

Comment: As a first step, I'd suggest to add    `WaitForSingleObject(hIncDataMutex, INFINITE);` in the `case FD_READ`, just before the line `   sReadBuffer = readBuffer;`

Comment: Tried already. It makes my program hang... My buffer is overwrote, for sure. But I do not see how to avoid that and synchronize everything.

Comment: Where does the programm hang ?  Could you try to analyse (log) further where it hangs ?

Comment: @JP744 Ok ! I see:  the hanging might be related to a buffer overflow or a socket read error.  I've made an edit.  If this doesn't help, ou have to put logging in both threads.  to see what happens in both.

Comment: It hangs in FD_READ, just befor sReadBuffer = readBuffer, probably because it never receive the mutex release ?

Comment: Ok. I investigated and logged a little bit more. The program makes 3 or 4 FD_READ "loops" before the thread is called.